# display the list<dictionary> value in table

Tags: jquery, list, model-view-controller

on button click i am trying to pass the page data into anther page.

this is my jquery code to invoke the controller

```
    $('#btn-Print').click(function () {
           debugger;
        var IsValid = true;
        var errorMessage = "Please notice the following errors<br /><br />";
        var packageID = $('#ddlPackage option:selected').val();
        if (packageID > 0)
{
            var reType = "Print";
            window.location.href = "/turnover/Turnover" + reType + "/" + 

    packageID;
            }
    });
```

here is my controller code

```
public ActionResult TurnoverPrint(Int32 ID)//(string packageID)
    {
        if (Session["UserID"] != null)
        {
            var client = new RestClient<DataTable>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiBaseAddress"]);
            var result = client.GetApiRequest("api/TurnoverReport/get?packageID=" + ID).Result;
            if (dataModel != null)
            {
                ViewBag.PackageName = dataModel.PackageName;
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                if (result != null)
                {
                    foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in result.Rows)
                    {
                        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                        foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in result.Columns)
                        {
                            if (col.ColumnName == "PackageDataID" || col.ColumnName == "IPC" || col.ColumnName == "From Date " || col.ColumnName == "To Date ")
                            {
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                row.Add(col.ColumnName, string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:n}", dr[col]));
                            }
                        }
                        rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                 return View(serializer.Serialize(rows));
            }
            else
            {
                return View(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
    }
```

here in **return View(serializer.Serialize(rows));** had the list of table values that has to be displayed in TurnoverPrint.cshtml view..

**row.Add(col.ColumnName, string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-IN"), "{0:n}", dr[col]));** this line is to get the numeric values in India currency format(currency culture)

how to read and handle the list values in the view. i have tried like

```
@model IEnumerable<System.Data.DataTable>
```

i know this is wrong approach..

please suggest me.

thank you..